# How to pull SQL Schema using DataReader

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, database-schema

Is there anyway we can pull SQL Database Schema from Table?

Following is my code but noway i could pull entire schema like

`Create Table Employee(code int, name blah blah...)`

```
Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim textInsertQueryLine As String
Dim tableSchema As DataTable
Dim tableField As DataRow
Dim tableProperty As DataColumn

Dim SourceConn As New SqlConnection(sourceDBPath)
Dim DestinationConn As New SqlConnection(destinationDBPath)

SourceConn.Open()
DestinationConn.Open()

sqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM sys.tables"

Dim cmdX As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, SourceConn)
Dim readerX As SqlDataReader = cmdX.ExecuteReader

Do While readerX.Read

    Dim cmdY As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, DestinationConn)
    Dim readerY As SqlDataReader = cmdY.ExecuteReader

    Do While readerY.Read

        If readerX.GetString(0) = readerY.GetString(0) Then
            txtConsoleView.AppendText(readerX.GetString(0) + "Matched. " + vbCrLf)
        Else

            tableSchema = readerX.GetSchemaTable()

            txtConsoleView.AppendText(tableSchema.ToString + vbCrLf)
        End If

    Loop
    readerY.Close()
Loop
readerX.Close()

SourceConn.Close()
DestinationConn.Close()
```

Comment: You can use [`SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: readerX.GetSchemaTable() i used this line but it is returning only table name

Comment: because you have used `SELECT name FROM sys.tables`, but you have to `SELECT *` from the real tables which were returned from  `sys.tables` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working approach which i've written from  scratch, so it's not really tested. It's using [`DataReader.GetSchemaTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.90).aspx) to list all columns of each table:

You can use these classes to map the schema informations, you can add more according to [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
Public Class Table
    Public Property DatabaseName As String
    Public Property TableName As String
    Public Property Schema As String
    Public Property FullName As String
    Public Property AllColumns As New List(Of TableColumn)

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return FullName
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TableColumn
    Public Property ColumnName As String
    Public Property DataType As Type
    Public Property Size As Int32
    Public Property ColumnOrdinal As Int32
    Public Property AllowDBNull As Boolean
    Public Property IsAutoIncrement As Boolean

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}({1})", ColumnName, DataType.ToString())
    End Function
End Class
```

This code reads all tables and all of their columns into a list:

```
Dim allTables As New List(Of Table)

Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.RM2ConnectionString) ' use your connection-string '
    Using sysTblCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Database]=DB_NAME(DB_ID()),FullName='['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']',[Schema]=SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),Name  FROM sys.tables ORDER BY schema_id,name", con)
        con.Open()
        Using readerSys = sysTblCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While readerSys.Read()
                Dim table As New Table()
                table.DatabaseName = readerSys.GetString(0)
                table.FullName = readerSys.GetString(1)
                table.Schema = readerSys.GetString(2)
                table.TableName = readerSys.GetString(3)
                allTables.Add(table)
            End While
        End Using
        For Each table In allTables
            Using tblCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & table.ToString(), con)
                tblCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
                Using rd = tblCommand.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim schemaTable As DataTable = rd.GetSchemaTable()
                    For Each row As DataRow In schemaTable.Rows
                        Dim col As New TableColumn()
                        col.ColumnName = row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName")
                        col.DataType = row.Field(Of Type)("DataType")
                        col.Size = row.Field(Of Int32)("ColumnSize")
                        col.ColumnOrdinal = row.Field(Of Int32)("ColumnOrdinal")
                        col.AllowDBNull = row.Field(Of Boolean)("AllowDBNull")
                        col.IsAutoIncrement = row.Field(Of Boolean)("IsAutoIncrement")
                        table.AllColumns.Add(col)
                    Next
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I am trying this code, but what is allTables.Add(table) ? Dataset or what? i couldn't find out

Comment: @kirk: sorry, i have not copy-pasted it, it is a List(Of Table). I have added it to the cide now.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining schema information from a database is accomplished with the process of schema discovery.

Schema discovery allows applications to request that managed providers find and return information about the database schema, also known as metadata, of a given database.

Different database schema elements such as tables, columns, and stored-procedures are exposed through schema collections.

Each schema collection contains a variety of schema information specific to the provider being used.

Each of the .NET Framework managed providers implement the GetSchema method in the Connection class, and the schema information that is returned from the GetSchema method comes in the form of a DataTable.

The GetSchema method is an overloaded method that provides optional parameters for specifying the schema collection to return, and restricting the amount of information returned.

More info: [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
   Sub Main()
      Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
      Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
         'Connect to the database then retrieve the schema information.
         connection.Open()
         Dim table As DataTable = connection.GetSchema("Tables")

         ' Display the contents of the table.
         DisplayData(table)
         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.")
         Console.ReadKey()
      End Using
   End Sub

   Private Function GetConnectionString() As String
      ' To avoid storing the connection string in your code,  
      ' you can retrieve it from a configuration file.
      Return "Data Source=(local);Database=AdventureWorks;" _
         & "Integrated Security=true;"
   End Function

   Private Sub DisplayData(ByVal table As DataTable)
      For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
         For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row(col))
         Next
         Console.WriteLine("============================")
      Next
   End Sub
End Module
```